# Show article from category Id mean.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

**Link Menu**

```
<a ui-sref="articles.list-nav({category: category.name})">
  {{ category.name }}</a>
```

**Route Client:**

```
.state('articles.list-nav', {
        url: '/:category/articles',
        templateUrl: 'modules/articles/views/list-articles-scategory.client.view.html',
        controller: 'ArticlesController'
      })
```

**List Article Category:**

```
<a class="md-12-line" ng-repeat="article in getArticles(category.id) ">
```

**Controller Client:**

```
$scope.getAticles = function(category){
             var result = [];
             for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.articles.length ; i++){
                 if(category === $scope.articless[i].category){
                     result.push($scope.articles[i]);
                 }
             }
             console.log(category);
             return result;
         };
```

**I tried the other way:**

**Controller Client:**

```
 $scope.subCat = $stateParams.subcategoria;
```

**List Article Category:**

```
<a class="md-12-line" ng-repeat="article in article | Filter: {(category: category.id)} ">
```

Example that I need:
menu IT: all article from category IT
menu marketing: All article from category Marketing

But not working anyway, can I help me?

Comment: whats the problem, any errors and whats the expected outcome?

Comment: Does not filter article for category and not show erros.
Using: 
 $scope.subCat = $stateParams.subcategoria;
And <a class="md-12-line" ng-repeat="article in article | Filter: {(category: category.id)} ">
Show all article, I need that work for category.
Using this way: <a class="md-12-line" ng-repeat="article in getArticles(category.id) ">
Not show anything.